# jQuery Callback data not loading in order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website dynamically loading content on a window.location.hash change event and I have a really annoying problem that I can't seem to fix. Essentially have 2 divs inside a body div; one with an id of 'loader-container' and the other is $mainContent so

```
<body>
   <div id=loader-container></div>
   <div $mainContent></div>
</body>
```

While loading the new page in $mainContent I want a spinning loading gif to show in 'loader-container'. The problem is that i cannot get the loader-container to load the content however $mainContent's data does load. Here is the js:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
    alert("This is being called");
    $('#loader-container').load('loading.php'); //this works here

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (newHash.substring(1,26) == "content/event.php?event_id"){

        $('#loader-container').load('loading.php'); //this doesnt work but the below code is being called inside the if statement

        $mainContent.slideUp("slow", function() {
            alert("This isnt being called!");
            alert("Below, loading.php isn't being loaded but newHash is");
            $('#loader-container').load('loading.php', function(){
                $mainContent.load(newHash, function() {         //this load's newHash successfully
                    $mainContent.show('slow', function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                        alert("this isn't being called");
                    });
                    alert("or this");
                });
                alert("or this");
            });
            $("#loader-container").hide();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You're missing a parentheses in `$'#loader-container')`. Is that in the real code or just a copying error? You're also missing a close parenthesis at the end, same question.

Comment: I copied it wrong, sorry. Should be $('#loader-container')